# How to animate multiple figures at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I made an animation for sorting algorithms and it it works great for animating one sorting algorithm, but when I try to animate multiple at the same time both windows come up but none of them are moving. I was wondering how I could go around to fix this.

When I run the code the first figure is stuck on the first frame and the second figure jumps to the last frame

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import random
# my class for getting data from sorting algorithms
from animationSorters import * 


def sort_anim(samp_size=100, types=['bubblesort', 'quicksort']):

    rndList = random.sample(range(1, samp_size+1), samp_size)
    anim = []
    for k in range(0, len(types)):

        sort_type = types[k]
        animation_speed = 1

        def barlist(x):
            if sort_type == 'bubblesort':
                l = bubblesort_swaps(x)#returns bubble sort data
            elif sort_type == 'quicksort':
                l = quicksort_swaps(x)#returns quick sort data

            final = splitSwaps(l, len(x)) 
            return final

        fin = barlist(rndList)

        fig = plt.figure(k+1)
        plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'black'

        n= len(fin)#Number of frames
        x=range(1,len(rndList)+1)
        barcollection = plt.bar(x,fin[0], color='w')

        anim_title = sort_type.title() + '\nSize: ' + str(samp_size)
        plt.title(anim_title)

        def animate(i):
            y=fin[i]
            for i, b in enumerate(barcollection):
                b.set_height(y[i])


        anim.append(animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, repeat=False, 
                    blit=False, frames=n, interval=animation_speed))

    plt.show()

sort_anim()
```

Comment: Any chance you can supply a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html?highlight=animation#module-matplotlib.animation) for the `animation` module:

> it is critical to keep a reference to the instance object. The
>   animation is advanced by a timer (typically from the host GUI
>   framework) which the Animation object holds the only reference to. If
>   you do not hold a reference to the Animation object, it (and hence the
>   timers), will be garbage collected which will stop the animation.

Therefore you need to return the references to your animations from your function, otherwise those objects are destroyed when exiting the function.

Consider the following simplification of your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np


def my_func(nfigs=2):
    anims = []
    for i in range(nfigs):
        fig = plt.figure(num=i)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        col = ax.bar(x=range(10), height=np.zeros((10,)))
        ax.set_ylim([0, 1])

        def animate(k, bars):
            new_data = np.random.random(size=(10,))
            for j, b in enumerate(bars):
                b.set_height(new_data[j])
            return bars,

        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(col, ), frames=100)
        anims.append(ani)

    return anims


my_anims = my_func(3)
# calling simply my_func() here would not work, you need to keep the returned
# array in memory for the animations to stay alive
plt.show()
```

Comment: I originally tried that but it still gave me my problem, that's why I tried to put the 
 `plt.show()`  inside of the function. I was playing around with it and I put a `pause` between the creation of the second figure and the animation started playing until the pause was over. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I got it to work by modifying it to return only one animations at a time, then add each of those individual to a list with a seperate function. Works perfectly now.